# How can I debug a variable error in Swift?

Tags: swift

Question: I am trying to answer this question with the code I have written in swift but I am getting an error. Can someone point out my issue?

You have a bowl on your counter with an even number of pieces of fruit in it. Half of them are bananas, and the other half are apples. You need 3 apples to make a pie.

Task
Your task is to evaluate the total number of pies that you can make with the apples that are in your bowl given to total amount of fruit in the bowl.

Input Format
An integer that represents the total amount of fruit in the bowl.

Output Format
An integer representing the total number of whole apple pies that you can make.

Sample Input
26

Sample Output
4

My Code:

```
var fullfruits: Int 

var applesapples = fullfruits / 2  

for fullfruits in 1...20

{

var pie = applesapples / 3

print (pie)

    fullfruits = fullfruits += 2

}
```

I need some assistance on this question. Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: line 1 error: variable defined here
line 2 error: variable 'fullfruits' used before being initialized

Comment: No need to debug when the compiler error tells you so clearly what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
var fullfruits: Int
var applesapples = fullfruits / 2
```

The problem here is that we are using `fullfruits` before initializing. That's the reason you get the error. If we initialize the variable, the code will compile just fine:

```
var fullfruits: Int = 26
var applesapples = fullfruits / 2
```

We can have a function to make solution more readable:

```
func pies(fruits: Int) -> Int {
    // Add your logic here
    return 0;
}

for i in 1...20 {
    print("With total", i, "fruits, we can make", pies(fruits: i), "pies")
}
```

Now, you can update the `pies` function to have the correct logic.

Comment: Thank you @AvmnuSng. How about if I have various test cases and I wanted to run it between a range from 1 to 20 using a for or for-in loop? Does my code in the description allow it to run? I've tried to run it and it gives me the error: Cannot assign to value: 'fullfruits' is a 'let' constant on line 7